# Is it able to get the player state with Samsung Smart TV SDK?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I have gone through the SEF plugin of the Samsung Smart TV API, and it seems there is no method like getState() or event like onstatechange...

Is there any method I can get the state of the player? Like 'Playing' or 'Pausing'?

or I can only self-defined a variable named `state` and change it time by time like the [video example](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00055/index.html)?

Any advice is pleased!

Comment: any news on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is nothing like that. You must manage state by your own. You should change it while invoking Play or Stop and on events ([like network error, etc...](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/sef_plugin_player.html))

Comment: any news on this topic? the url above is not working :/

Comment: After change of Guide document is moved to http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/API00005/Player_172.html